# ionic4 background image/color is not show up

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic4

I'm trying to set a background image or background color but it does not appear
Background image - There is an error on the url
Background color - no error appears but no background appears either ...

```css
scss:

:host{
    ion-content.bg-image{
        background: url('assets/homebackround.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
html:

<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      ionic4
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="bg-image" no-scroll padding>
  
</ion-content>
```

[image: the result]

Comment: [ng] Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
[ng] (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\This_User\catch\src\app\home\home.page.scss:3:20: Can't resolve 'assets/homebackround.jpg' in 'C:\Users\This_User\catch\src\app\home'
[ng]   1 | :host{[ng]   2 |     ion-content.bg-image{[ng] > 3 |         --backgroung: url('assets/homebackround.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
[ng]     |                    ^
[ng]   4 |     }
[ng]   5 | }
[ng]
[ng] i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: can you check if you have given proper path of image and proper image name as well, as in error above it says Can't resolve 'assets/homebackround.jpg'

Comment: If path is correct then try path as '../assets//homebackround.jpg'

Comment: I've checked the path and it's true,
I've also tried the path you wrote
Still the same error

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the css property given by Ionic4 and 
here is how you can use it.

```
ion-content{
    --background: url('assets/homebackround.jpg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
}
```

Here is running code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-background)

Comment: @s.k. have a look at he stackblitz attached to my answer